# angulartics2 with piwik is tracking an url with double #

Tags: analytics, angular5, matomo, angulartics2

I have integrated angulartics2 with Piwik in my angular 5 application & successfully found the URL tracks in the Piwik admin module after observing the URL tracked I found that http://localhost:4200/#/app/#/app/main-route/sub-route.

Below is the code used according to demo

1. In index.html added Piwik tracking code with _paq statements commented
2. In app.module.ts

   ```
   @NgModule({
        imports : [Angulartics2Module.forRoot([Angulartics2Piwik])]
   });
   ```
3. In app.component.ts

   ```
   export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
       constructor(private angulartics2: Angulartics2) {
       }
   }
   ```

Can anyone know why it is behaving like that?

Thanks in advance.
Sampat